# HOW TO query multi-valued column by key in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, multivalue

How to query a `multivalued` column for a specific key?

Sample Data

```
ID   DAY              PRICE
1    01;02;03;04;...  100;230;110;34.5;...
2    01;02;03;04;...  120;240;510;34.5;...
```

For example:

select ... where DAY key = '02'

Expected:

```
ID DAY PRICE
1  02  230
2  02  240
```

**Notes**

The actual table has over 30 fields.

Joining multiple `CROSS APPLY SPLIT_STRING` looked like a tedious solution

Comment: there exists a function called `STRING_SPLIT` for version 2016+ if it's yours.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan i tried it. you would need to re-construct the source table field by field, then join. the actual table has over 30 fields... i was hoping for a more clever way of doing this

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu, most clever way is to store details in a separate table. If refactoring of the db is not possible, use `[DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD]`  sp which contrary to `STRING_SPLIT` returns tokens numbered, so you can easily match tokens from two (30) columns by the token number.

Comment: @Serg will try, thanks

Comment: Ideally though, you should be fixing your design, by normalising it and not storing multiple values in a single value.

Comment: Tedious solutions are often the price you pay for bad database design.

Comment: Not my design  ... data was loaded from a MV platform, i'm just trying to move parts of it to SQL Server

Comment: @Larnu you see the extract i included from the ETL, we inherit/ have to manage existing systems, not always pretty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution uses cte and I hope it works for you:

```
with cte1 as
( 
select id, value daykey,
 row_number() over(order by (select null)) as rowid
from mvct
cross apply string_split(day, ";")
),
cte2 as
(
select id, value pricekey,
 row_number() over(order by (select null)) as rowid
from mvct
cross apply string_split(price, ";")
)
select cte1.id, cte1.daykey, cte2.pricekey
from cte1
inner join cte2 on cte1.id = cte2.id
and cte1.rowid = cte2.rowid
and cte1.daykey = "02"
```

Comment: Thanks, i eventually used a variant of this -- it was the simplest solution

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option that will dynamically unpivot your data (without actually using dynamic SQL), and then pivot the results.

You would just have to list the 30 columns in the `for Item in (...)` portion

**Cross Apply B** will convert the **ROW** into XML

**Cross Apply C** will **UNPIVOT** the XML

**Cross Apply D** will parse/split the delimited string (with a sequence) from C

Then it becomes a small matter for the PIVOT

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] varchar(50),[DAY] varchar(50),[PRICE] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'01;02;03;04','100;230;110;34.5')
,(2,'01;02;03;04','120;240;510;34.5')

Select *
 From  (
        Select A.ID
              ,C.Item
              ,D.*
         From  @YOurTable A
         Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml))) B(XMLData)
         Cross Apply (
                        Select Item  = xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)')
                              ,Value = xAttr.value('.','varchar(max)')
                         From  XMLData.nodes('//@*') xNode(xAttr)
                         Where xAttr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('Id','Other-Columns','To-Exclude')
                     ) C
         Cross Apply (
                        Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by (Select null))
                              ,RetVal = ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(100)')))
                        From  ( values (cast('<x>' + replace(C.Value,';','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml))) as A(x)
                        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                     ) D
        ) src
 Pivot (max(RetVal) for Item in ([Day],[Price]) ) pvt
 Where Day='02'
```

**Returns**

```
ID  RetSeq  Day Price
1   2       02  230
2   2       02  240
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find  the original `DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD` function code at https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2

Demo for 2 columns

```
select id, details.[day], details.price
from (
     values
     (1,'01;02;03;04','100;230;110;34.5')
    ,(2,'01;02;03;04','120;240;510;34.5')
) t (ID,[Day],Price)
cross apply (
    select d.item [day], p.item price
    from DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD([Day],';') d
    join DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD(Price,';') p on d.ItemNumber = p.ItemNumber
) details
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can create an additional FUNCTION in your database, you can use this following script to get your desired output.

**Create Function:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION FIND_CHARINDEX
(@TargetStr   VARCHAR(8000), 
 @SearchedStr VARCHAR(8000), 
 @Occurrence  INT
)
RETURNS INT
AS
     BEGIN
         DECLARE @pos INT, @counter INT, @ret INT;
         SET @pos = CHARINDEX(@TargetStr, @SearchedStr);
         SET @counter = 1;
         IF @Occurrence = 1
             SET @ret = @pos;
             ELSE
             BEGIN
                 WHILE(@counter < @Occurrence)
                     BEGIN
                         SELECT @ret = CHARINDEX(@TargetStr, @SearchedStr, @pos + 1);
                         SET @counter = @counter + 1;
                         SET @pos = @ret;
         END;
         END;
         RETURN(@ret);
     END;
```

**SELECT Statement:**

```
DECLARE @S_String VARCHAR(20) = '05'
DECLARE @S_String_New VARCHAR(20) = ';'+@S_String+';'

SELECT 
REVERSE(
    SUBSTRING(
        REVERSE(
            SUBSTRING(
                ';'+Day+';',
                0, 
                (CHARINDEX(@S_String_New,';'+Day+';',0)+LEN(@S_String)) +1
            )
        ),
        0,
        CHARINDEX(
            ';',
            REVERSE(SUBSTRING(';'+Day+';',0, (CHARINDEX(@S_String_New,';'+Day+';',0)+LEN(@S_String)) +1)),
            0
        )
    )
),

REVERSE(
    SUBSTRING(
        REVERSE(
            SUBSTRING(
                ';'+PRICE+';',
                0,    
                (
                    dbo.FIND_CHARINDEX(
                        ';',
                        ';'+PRICE+';',
                        (
                            LEN(SUBSTRING(';'+Day+';',0, (CHARINDEX(@S_String_New,';'+Day+';',0)+LEN(@S_String)) +1)) 
                                - LEN(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(';'+Day+';',0,  (CHARINDEX(@S_String_New,';'+Day+';',0)+LEN(@S_String))  +1),';',''))+1
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        0,
        CHARINDEX(
            ';',
            REVERSE(
                SUBSTRING(
                    ';'+PRICE+';',
                    0,    
                    (
                        dbo.FIND_CHARINDEX(
                            ';',
                            ';'+PRICE+';',   
                            (
                                LEN(SUBSTRING(';'+Day+';',0, (CHARINDEX(@S_String_New,';'+Day+';',0)+LEN(@S_String)) +1)) 
                                    - LEN(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(';'+Day+';',0,  (CHARINDEX(@S_String_New,';'+Day+';',0)+LEN(@S_String))  +1),';',''))+1
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
            1
        )
    )
)
FROM your_table
WHERE ';'+Day+';' LIKE '%'+@S_String_New+'%'
```